# How to copy data from one canvas to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have forms with arbitrary numbers of canvases. Once one is filled out I would like to copy it to any other canvas that is interacted with.

I have currently

When one canvase is closed I save the canvas data

```
sourceCanvas = $(this).find('canvas')[0];
```

Then when the next one loads (they are in modals)

I try to populate it like this

```
var destCtx = $(this).find('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
```

I am getting this error

Uncaught

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type
>   '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

Is ('canvas')[0] the wrong thing to grab? should I be getting something else in the canvas element?

Thanks!

Comment: I bet your `this` is not pointing to where you expect

Comment: If you could provide the complete code  instead of just pieces, we may be able to better help you. To me it sounds like `sourceCanvas` is outside the scope or smth like that when calling drawImage (the error says drawImage is a CanvasRenderingContext2D, so it seems to have been set correctly)

Answer (score 0):

> When one canvase is closed I save the canvas data
>
> `sourceCanvas = $(this).find('canvas')[0];`

I think that your code is not accessing the image data in the source canvas.
Call `getImageData()` on the context of the source canvas then get call `putImageData()` on the context of the destination canvas
.
Below is a simple example which copies the image data from canvas1 into both canvas1 (at a different location for illustration) and also into canvas2.

Also, check out this excellent text on [HTML5 Canvas](http://corehtml5canvas.com/).

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #f00;">no canvas</canvas>

<canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #00f;">no canvas</canvas>


<script>
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
ctx1.fillStyle = "red";
ctx1.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

function copy() {
    var imgData = ctx1.getImageData(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx1.putImageData(imgData, 10, 70);
    ctx2.putImageData(imgData, 10, 70);
}
</script>

<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]